# new attribute in table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need help if anyone know how it happens in IE5 and how to correct in IE11

I just started looking into an issue. There was an web application where they were using only in IE and the compatibility mode was IE5. Now I am migrating the compatibility mode to IE11 (Edge). I see the below line of code and it is working fine in IE5 compatibility, but in IE11 it is throwing undefined.

```
<td style='text-align: left;' class='isEditable-no' dataType='customerGciNo'>
```

...

**javascript:**

```
alert(oCell.dataType);      -> output: customerGciNo     -> in IE5
alert(oCell.dataType);      -> output: undefined         -> in IE11
```

Could you please help how to get it work in IE11 compatibility mode

Comment: *"Now I am migrating the compatibility mode to IE11 (Edge)"* Which is it, IE11, or Edge? (Or both?) They're different browsers.

Comment: I am migrating to Edge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an attribute from an element, you use `getAttribute`:

```
alert(oCell.getAttribute("dataType"));
```

The old code was relying on the attribute being *automatically reflected* as a property on the element. I didn't know IE5 did that; certainly no modern browser does.

---

Side note: Using custom attributes on elements without using the `data-*` prefix is invalid according to spec. (It works, it's just invalid.) So you could change that to `data-type="customerGciNo"` to make it valid, then use `getAttribute("data-type")`. Modern browsers also support the [`dataSet` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) which reflects `data-*` attributes, and so you could read it with `oCell.dataSet.type`.

Comment: @SKumar You should check it as an answer.

Comment: @SaidbakR: He/she probably will, once he/she can -- there's a 15-minute lockout before you can do that.